# How to check/assign user's roles right after signing in?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

For my application when the user logs in I need to check if they have any roles assigned to them and if they don't assign them a basic role. Also based on their role I have to redirect them to certain pages. But I can't find a way to check/set user's roles when they sign in.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
              {
               if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                 {
                      FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                     if(User.IsInRole("User")) 
//This won't work becauser User is not populated yet. It will be populated only on next request for some reason that has to do with setting cookies
    }
```

Any ideas how to work this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `Roles.IsUserInRole` method allows to pass string as username, so it makes possible to check users membership without calling the User object.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this?

```
if(User.IsInRole(model.UserName, "User"))
```

Comment: Well the problem is that something like that doesn't work when User just signs in. User object is empty. It gets populated with data only on next request. I have explained that in the inline comment in my code block.

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry for this answer! I've just wanted to write that you could call RoleProvider directly, with 2 parameters, like in you answer and misprinted, typed User instead of Roles. Man, sorry...